# Javascript Time issue doesn't think that I am between a startTime and an endTime

Tags: javascript, time

The .js file and the .vbs file launch up with no errors fortunately. But, for some strange reason, the execution always ends believing that I am not between the two times. Keep in mind the current hour is 22 at where I am, so what is preventing me?
Here is the code:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();
var timeEnd = d.setHours(23);
var timeStart = d.setHours(0);
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application"); 
var commandtoRun = "C:\\Users\\100046908\\Desktop\\Letsgo.vbs";

if(n < timeEnd && n > timeStart){
var r = confirm("Press a button");
if (r = true) {
x = "You pressed OK!";
_system.shutDown();
} else {
x = "You pressed Cancel!";
die;
}
}
 else { 
oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,"","","open","1");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The return from *getHours* is the current hour for the date (from 0 to 23 inclusive), there return from *setHours* is a time value in milliseconds since the epoch, a very, very much larger number. So *n* will always be less than both *timeEnd* and *timeStart*. Try `n = +d` so it represents the current time value.

Answer (score 0):

`n` is the return value of `d.getHours()`. It is a natural number, which is smaller than 24. On the other hand, you have this initialization:

```
var timeEnd = d.setHours(23);
var timeStart = d.setHours(0);
```

since `d.setHours` returns the numeric reprezentation of the date, a value like 1459370582692, `n` will never be between `timeStart` and `timeEnd`. You might wanted to do this instead:

```
var timeEnd = 23;
var timeStart = 0;
```

Comment: Or `n = d.getTime()`. ;-)